# Two adunits from different ad mob accounts . Is it possible?

Tags: android, admob

So the scenario is like I have an android app with one admob ad banner at bottom of page,
Now I also have two admob accounts one of my friends and one of me and hence we want to display two ad units in rotation , Is this possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes you can.

Long answer: To do it exactly as specified will involved some tedious coding. You are better off just randomly choosing between your AdUnitIds on app startup and use that Id for the lifetime of the app. It will be much simpler, and will average out to exactly the same return.